# How to properly type-hint a Python dict whose keys are Type[T] and values are generics of that type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'd like to have a dict hinted such that the values contain generics of a type that's the same as the key:

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Dict, List, Type, TypeVar

class Event(ABC):
    pass

class MessageReceived(Event):
    pass

class MessageSent(Event):
    pass

EventT = TypeVar("EventT", bound=Event)

events: Dict[Type[EventT], List[EventT]] = {}
```

mypy returns an error along the lines of:

```
Type variable "EventT" is unbound  [valid-type]
```

I understand why `EventT` is unbound, but I cannot work out a way to actually hint this properly.

Comment: I don't fully understand, what you wan to achieve. But wouldn't `List[Event]` (as value type specification, ofc) do what you need?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to create a "registry" of Events, where each of the Dict's values are of the type of Event specified by the Dict's key.

Comment: so you want each item in the dict to have its type governed by the type of its key? I don't think mypy can do that...

Answer (score 0):

Consider declaring an `EventRecord` type that will represent the relation between the event type and the list of events.

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Event(ABC):
    pass


class MessageReceived(Event):
    pass


class MessageSent(Event):
    pass


EventT = TypeVar("EventT", bound=Event)


@dataclass
class EventRecord(Generic[EventT]):
    event_type: type[EventT]
    events: list[EventT] = field(default_factory=list)


event_registry = {
    EventRecord(event_type=MessageSent),
    EventRecord(event_type=MessageReceived),
}
```