# Typing a Python dictionary as Dict[key[T], value[K]] where T and K are restricted

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pyright

**Here is the problem:**

I have a dictionary that keeps track of two different types of values (let's say `city` and `village`) using two different types of keys (`city_key` and `village_key`). I'd like to annotate this dictionary with generics, so that when the dictionary receives key of type `city_key` mypy/Pyright should annotate the return value as `city`. Likewise, if you try to assign a `city` value to a `village_key`, mypy/pyright should throw an error.

The alternative is to maintain two different dictionaries, one for cities and one for villages, but I am curious if I can get away with one dictionary.

**What I've tried so far**

I researched this issue, but couldn't find a definitive example / answer. There is a question just like mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649900/how-to-properly-type-hint-a-python-dict-whose-keys-are-typet-and-values-are-ge), but it went unanswered.

**Some pseudo code to show what I am aiming for in practice**

```py
# two types of aliased keys
# ... edited to use NewType as per juanpa.arrivillaga comment

CityKey = NewType("CityKey", str)
VillageKey = NewType("VillageKey", str)

# two types of values, city and village
class City:...
class Village:...

# key generator that returns city or village key based on type of input
def generate_key(settlement: City | Village) -> CityKey | VillageKey: ...

# declare some keys & values
london = City("London")
london_key = generate_key(london)
mousehole = Village("Mousehole")
mousehole_key = generate_key(village)

# instantiate the dictionary
data: [????] = {}

# assign city to city key, and village to village key
data[london_key] = london
data[mousehole_key] = mousehole

# trying to assign village to city key should raise a type check error
data[london_key] = mousehole

# type of value accessed by village key should be village
reveal_type(data[mousehole_key]) # Type[Village]
```

Thank you!

PS
I am not sure if I am using the term `covariant` properly in the title. Let me know if I am not.

Comment: Have you thought about using a nested dictionary? You could have a single dictionary (say d) where d['city'] can point to cities and d['village'] can point to villages. So it would look like d['city'][london_key] = london and d['village'][mousehole_key] = mousehole.

Comment: @AkankshaAtrey this question is about type annotations

Comment: Note, covariant doesn't really apply here, variance describes how subtyping relationships work with generics. Also note, you have **only a single type (`str`)** aliased in two different ways, `CityKey` and `VillageKey`,but it will still be treated as the same type. You either need to explicitly subclass `str` to make new types **or** use the convenience function [`typing.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType) which doesn't create a distinct runtime type but lets the static type checker know that they should be treated as such

Comment: In any case, I don't think there is any way to express this using `dict[K, V]` directly, but you could probably wrap accessing the dictionary in a function and use `typing.overload` on the function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I understood. The reason for the suggestion was Ely can then do instance based sanity checks more easily when assigning new entries. Otherwise there is no simple way to type cast within a single dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typing.overload` for this purpose, which can help us go from types like `Callable[[A1 | B1], A2 | B2]` to one where it can be either `Callable[[A1], A2]` or `Callable[[B1], B2]`, and a subclass of `dict`.

```
from typing import overload

@overload
def generate_key(settlement: City) -> CityKey:
    # Just a stub
    ...


@overload
def generate_key(settlement: Village) -> VillageKey:
    # Just a stub
    ...


def generate_key(settlement):
    # Contains the actual implementation
    [...]


class CityOrVillageDict(dict):
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: CityKey, value: City) -> None:
        # Just a stub
        ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: VillageKey, value: Village) -> None:
        # Just a stub
        ...

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Overloaded functions need an implementation
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: CityKey) -> City:
        # Just a stub
        ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: VillageKey) -> Village:
        # Just a stub
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Overloaded functions need an implementation
        return super().__getitem__(key)

data = CityOrVillageDict()
```